# Galaxy s2 is recognised by computer but doesn't charge

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb, charging

This is an odd one but today I noticed by S2 wasn't charging while plugged in. I tried connecting it to the computer and it came up as a media device as normal but still didn't charge, the battery percentage went down until it was 0% and the phone shut off.

Is there any way I can fix this myself?

Comment: Can you get your hands on another S2 USB cable and try that first? Then look into a new battery and other solutions after that. It's often something simple like that. I had a damaged and a generic Micro USB for a HTC phone and I could copy to and from it but not charge with either, same as you, and when I used the mains outlet it took about 16 hours to charge!

Comment: Does it charge when you plug into AC? It could be that the USB port simply doesn't provide enough power.

Comment: @RossC Will look at getting another USB cable but I don't think that's the issue because charging my Nexus 7 with the same cable works fine.

Comment: @AlEverett Doesn't work over AC either. The battery icon in the status bar looked as though it was charging (had the lightning symbol) but the phone said 'Please connect your charger'.

Comment: I suspect a bad battery, then.

Comment: @AlEverett Good suspicion! Cleaned the battery contacts and it appears to be charging as normal. :)

Comment: @Sam Great! Glad to hear it's fixed. It is often something small like that at fault. It's easy to go wild flashing ROMS and going down the complicated route. I had a friend spend 4 hours reinstalling kernels, drivers, etc etc and his brother came along did a battery pull and everything that was wrong was fixed immediately!